# Сравнение двух списков

Tags: c#, коллекции

Здравствуйте, есть два списка с доменами, первый содержит 1000 элементов, второй - 20000; суть вопроса такова: нужно определить, содержит ли второй список конкретный элемент первого списка или нет. И так нужно пробежаться по всей коллекции из 1000 элементов.
Просто пробегаться циклами - не вариант, сделать LINQ запрос?

Comment: Предложенные вам ответы содержат хорошие варианты решения: HashSet, сортировка, распараллеливание. Чтобы дать вам более конкретный ответ, укажите тип ваших элементов и тип используемых коллекций, а также, можно ли взять другие коллекции.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за внимание уделенное моему вопросу.
Тип элементов - string, думаю использовать List<T>.
Сама задачка на английском:

We would like to perform lookups to see if input URL domain name is listed in the blacklist. Simply looping over the list and doing string based comparison is not an option. If I do 1000 lookups it's simply too slow. 
Lookup must return positive match if domain is blacklisted, for example, if a.biz TLD is blacklisted, mycompany.a.biz should return positive match. 
On the other hand, b.biz should not match, because sub-domain is different.

Comment: _too slow_ - это бред. [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect(v=vs.110).aspx) на коллекциях размером 1000 и 20000 отрабатывает мгновенно. И вообще, никто не будет делать за вас домашнуюю работу. Покажите свои попытки решения, приведите свой код. Укажите, в чём именно проблема.

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от того, что ты преследуешь.

**Производительность**

Если ожидаешь, что LINQ тебе даст тебе повысит производительность, то это ерунда.

LINQ трансформируется в `foreach` производительность будет ничуть не больше.

Если домены это строки, то лучше воспользоваться `HashSet<T>` и вычитанием одного множества из другого, производительность должна быть выше нежели у обычных списков.

**Лаконичность**

С этой целью LINQ справляется.

Comment: Если конечно в *.config нет такой штуки: <UseRandomizedStringHashAlgorithm enabled="1" />